# What is the difference between `{{ }}` and `{!! !!}` when using forms?

Tags: forms, laravel

I'm learning Laravel but I am confused. When using forms, what is the difference between using exclamation marks vs another curly bracket? Both seem to accomplish the same thing.

`{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'post_store', 'class' => 'form')) !!}`

`{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'post_store', 'class' => 'form')) }}`

Comment: wow, Taylor Swift also do code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{!! !!}` will escape your data.

A good use for this would be, for example, making your links clickable.

So if `$data = "www.google.com";`, for example,

`{{ $data }}` is not clickable.

`{!! $data !!}` will  be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Hello, {!! $name !!}.

htmlspecialchars function prevent XSS attacks by escaping (not execute) codes that entered by user in text area or text field, just display as it is, code if executed could harm your application.

Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a security breach that takes advantage of dynamically generated Web pages. In an XSS attack, a Web application is sent with a script that activates when it is read by an unsuspecting user's browser or by an application that has not protected itself against cross-site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

The reason these syntax differences do not result in any output difference is because Laravel Blade does not escape instances of `Illuminate\Support\HtmlString` which `Form::open()` returns.

Therefore, the escape syntax `{{ Form::open() }}` and the unescaped syntax `{!! Form::open() !!}` will both be handled without escaping.  HtmlString is used in several areas to avoid escaping necessary HTML including `csrf_field()`.