# What does this {!! !!} mean?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I found this line that's used to create a form label displayed in HTML, however, I'm not so sure what does {!! !!} actually do.

```
{!!Form::label('username', 'Username', ['class =>'control-label']) !!}
```

Note: the page is also using javascript and is saved as .php.

Comment: Duplicate: [What is the difference between \`{{ }}\` and \`{!! !!}\` when using forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985058/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-using-forms)

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - the given question is not related to pure HTML after all

Comment: @NicoHaase, sorry for that but I added HTML as it is creating a form and i'm not sure what {!! !!} really is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{!! !!}` in Laravel blades to display unescaped data